# Strings 'null', 'true', 'false' etc. to actual nulls, trues and falses in JS

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

In JS we can convert strings with numbers to actual numbers by multiplication by 1, like so:

```
'0'*1 //= 0
```

But unfortunately similar tricks with strings like `'null', 'true', 'false'` don't work:

```
'false'*0 //= NaN
!!'false' //= true
```

What's the optimal way for such conversions in JS? Are there any native methods doing this?

Comment: `JSON.parse`? `eval`? Why, in what use case, do you need to do this?

Comment: So what will be result of `"Stack" *5` , to start with ?

Comment: I wouldn't use `eval`, you're asking for code injection this way. JavaScript has [truthy and falsey](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Glossaire/Truthy) values. They should help you most of the time. In my projects, I sometimes use a function that does comparisons for type checking.

Comment: 'false' is actually truthy and not falsy

Comment: @NinaScholz lol

Comment: yep, correct. so make a global function that cleverly tests different values?

Comment: please add the wanted results as well after checking/converting.

Comment: @NinaScholz Ahh I already wrote code for `"stack stack stack stack stack"` :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSON.parse to convert them

```
JSON.parse('false') // false
JSON.parse('true')  // true
JSON.parse('null')  // null
```

This won't work for `undefined`, or `NaN` though

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object with then various types and use it as check and value storage.

```js
function getValue(v) {
    var properties = {
            false: false,
            true: true,
            null: null,
            undefined: undefined,
            NaN: NaN
        };

    return v in properties ? properties[v] : v;
}

console.log(getValue('true'), typeof getValue('true'));
console.log(getValue('false'), typeof getValue('false'));
console.log(getValue('null'), typeof getValue('null'));
console.log(getValue('undefined'), typeof getValue('undefined'));
console.log(getValue('NaN'), typeof getValue('NaN'));
console.log(getValue('foo'), typeof getValue('foo'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write the obvious code. (Example code in ES6. Adjust as needed, or use Babel or TypeScript.)

```
const f = x => {
    if (x === 'true') { return true }
    if (x === 'false') { return false }
    if (x === 'null') { return null }

    return undefined
}
```

If you are handling JSON input, then use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: but is that code necessary having JSON.parse? isn't that reinventing the wheel?

Comment: It depends on what you want. If you want to turn _only those strings_ into only those values, then use the above. If you want to parse JSON, use `JSON.parse`.